# GNUPLOT how to add more space to indexes in labels

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I try to put the space to the index in the letters of the labels of Gnuplot. I use the following command:

```
    set terminal pngcairo size 500,400 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
    set output 'test.png'
    set xlabel 'atan(~{/Symbol w}{.6\~}_2)'
    set ylabel 'atan(~{/Symbol w}{.6\~}_2)'
    plot sin(x)
```

As you can see from the plot here the `_2` over-plot the symbol. Could someone help me to understand how to put extra space to the indexes?

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly, this is a bit of a hacky solution but it seems to work:

```
set xlabel 'atan(~{/Symbol w}{.6\~} _2)'
set ylabel 'atan(~{/Symbol w}{.6\~} _2)'
```

Adding the space after the symbol means that the subscript `2` doesn't overlap with it:

[image: graph with no overlap]